# Android Development on RPi3

Tags: android, cross-compilation

My RPi is the Raspberry Pi 3

I have access to a Dell PowerEdge running Ubuntu (Not server) 17, x86_64 
processor

I have a cross-compiler for the RPi on the PowerEdge

---

I only have access to the PE for about 15 minutes a day during school hours. (It was donated to us by Southwire, a friend and I have an HTTP server running on it)

I would like to be able to do Android development, but I do not have anything able to compile my source into an APK. (I use an app called AIDE on my phone for the editing, but it doesn't compile) Any potential devices at home do not work:

A Toshiba Satellite - A 32-bit processor on Windows 7 with 2GB of RAM

My Android Phone -- AIDE is a piece of crap and never compiles

Two desktop towers that would work but my dad won't let me use them

My mom's laptop would work ok, but she won't let me.

---

None of those work. I would like to use the cross-compiler on the PE to build whatever tools I need to compile the Java into an APK. I - 1) Don't know how exactly how to compile the tools, and 2) Don't even know what all tools to compile.

Thanks!

P.S. I have seen other questions about this, but they all just state that it can't be done, and my idea doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere. Also, I do not mean to install Android Studio or any IDE, just the bare minimum to get my APKs compiled.

P.S.2:
The cross-compiler I have on the PowerEdge is located on Github at https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the cross-toolchain generator crosstool-NG, e.g., 
   https://github.com/anod/crosstool-ng-samples and http://crosstool-ng.github.io/

I guess it should be possible to set up an RPi-based toolchain for Android dev - if that's what you are looking to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate a bit? I don't really know what a toolchain is, what it does, or how to use it

Comment: It's the bundle of build tools that get you from your code to a working executable. Crosstool-NG generates a cross-compiler, libraries, linker, debugger, etc. It's for C & C++, not Java, so I don't know if it'll help you at all. 

Note that IDEs are built on top of toolchains.